# MySql Stored Procedure error in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write my first mySql stored procedure and keep on getting an error from the server that I am unable to understand, hope someone will be able to help me fixing it.

**What I am doing**
I collect some parameters from social networks, and I need to save this data in two different tables. I know that the table schema might not be optimal, but this is something I cannot change at the moment.

The idea is that I call the stored procedure from my server-side code passing in article ID and some other parameters, and the procedure:

1. Updates the "articles" table
2. Inserts anew record into the "popularity" tables with some values that are the result of the previous UPDATE

This is the stored procedure I wrote

```
BEGIN
UPDATE
  articles2
SET
  fb_shares = n_shares,
  fb_comments = n_comments,
  fb_reactions = n_reactions,
  tw_tweets = @tweets :=(tw_tweets + n_tweets),
  tw_retweets = @retweets :=(tw_retweets + n_retweets),
  tw_favorites = @favorites :=(tw_favorites + n_favorites),
  tw_reach = @reach :=(tw_reach + n_reach),
  tw_since_id = n_since_id,
  popularity = @popularity :=(
    (n_shares * fb_shares_weight) +(
      n_comments * fb_comments_weight
    ) +(
      n_reactions * fb_reactions_weight
    ) +(@tweets * tw_tweets_weight) +(@retweets * tw_retweets_weight) +(
      @favorites * tw_favorites_weight
    ) +(@reach * tw_reach_weight)
  ),
  popularity_updated =(popularity_updated + 1)
WHERE
  id = n_id ;
INSERT
INTO
  popularity(
    article_id,
    added,
    popularity,
    tw_tweets,
    tw_reach,
    tw_favorites,
    tw_retweets,
    tw_since_id,
    fb_shares,
    fb_comments,
    fb_reactions
  )
VALUES(
  n_id,
  NOW(), @popularity, @tweets, @reach, @favorites, @retweets, n_since_id, n_shares, n_comments, n_reactions) ;
END
```

I keep getting an error `#1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field` and the INSERT is never performed. I suppose that the variables assignment is wrong, but cannot understand how to fix it.

As said, I never wrote a stored procedure before, and since that line looks correct to me, I really cannot understand what's wrong. I cannot exclude that I am trying to do something that should not be done with a stored procedure, but the few examples that I found online makes me think this should be correct...

Thank you in advance,
Simone

Edit:

I got rid of that error, but still the `INSERT` is not performed... here is the updated stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
SET @tweets := 0, @retweets := 0, @favorites := 0, @reach := 0, @popularity := 0;
UPDATE
  articles2
SET
  fb_shares = n_shares,
  fb_comments = n_comments,
  fb_reactions = n_reactions,
  tw_tweets = @tweets :=(tw_tweets + n_tweets),
  tw_retweets = @retweets :=(tw_retweets + n_retweets),
  tw_favorites = @favorites :=(tw_favorites + n_favorites),
  tw_reach = @reach :=(tw_reach + n_reach),
  tw_since_id = n_since_id,
  popularity = @popularity :=(
    (n_shares * fb_shares_weight) +(
      n_comments * fb_comments_weight
    ) +(
      n_reactions * fb_reactions_weight
    ) +(@tweets * tw_tweets_weight) +(@retweets * tw_retweets_weight) +(
      @favorites * tw_favorites_weight
    ) +(@reach * tw_reach_weight)
  ),
  popularity_updated =(popularity_updated + 1)
WHERE
  id = n_id ;
SELECT @tweets, @retweets, @favorites, @reach, @popularity;
INSERT
INTO
  popularity(
    article_id,
    added,
    popularity,
    tw_tweets,
    tw_reach,
    tw_favorites,
    tw_retweets,
    tw_since_id,
    fb_shares,
    fb_comments,
    fb_reactions
  )
VALUES(
  n_id,
  NOW(), @popularity, @tweets, @reach, @favorites, @retweets, n_since_id, n_shares, n_comments, n_reactions) ;
END
```

Comment: Which of the fields mentioned contains spatial data?

Comment: As far as I understand none of them, are just INTEGERS or FLOATS.

Comment: That's what I assumed, I'd check the definition of the popularity table to make sure.

Comment: Thanks I'll check!

Comment: You're right, for some reason the `added` field was defined as `geometry` instead of `datetime`. Fixed that, now the stored procedure works. I could have spent days trying to figure out what was wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome. I've added an answer to that effect below which you can accept to close off the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the definition of the `popularity` table for a field defined with data type GEOMETRY and change to appropriate type.